# Ubuntu crash after each Windows 10 boot since update

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, crash

I'm hitting a really strange bug:

A few day ago, booting on my W10, I didn't have other choice than seeing it make by-himself the Fall update that I was denying him (I was sure it'll break my triple-boot/dual HDD config, I was right...)

Since then, every time I boot my Ubuntu after a W10 boot, my Ubuntu crash after 10 minutes and restart by himself.

But it only happen for the first boot of Ubuntu after a W10 boot: I can boot flawlessly my Ubuntu after as much as I want.

Regards,
Blag

Comment: Do you use hybrid standby? Do you use dual gpus?

Comment: @davidbaumann It's a laptop G75V, single GPU, I don't use anything than the true shutdown on the W10 (Or maybe the update mess up this ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found!

As @davidbaumann said, it was the fake windows shut-down.

Seem the Fall update force-enable the Quick-boot feature, even if you've disable it, as said here: [reddit/win_10_reenabled_fast_startup](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/7hpdwz/win_10_reenabled_fast_startup_in_the_latest/).

Disable it again solve the issue (but Windows "I'll do it no matter what you said" start to really p*ss-me off...)